# Texturing going crazy!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

So I'm trying to model a can of Coca Cola. I use Cylinder projection and then scale it. I use cycles and I use the image texture node to go into diffuse BSDF color node and then from the BDSF output to material output surface. When I apply texture it goes crazy, it even creates texture on the parts I didn't select to have a texture! (see photos)
I'm new to blender so any help would be nice.

Thanks in advance, Seppe

[image: When applying texture]

[image: When The Texture Goes Crazy]

Comment: your UV doesn't seem straight, first thing choose front orthogonal view and unwrap again (with cylinder mode)

Comment: I used the view on numpad 1 to select the faces and then I fitted the square to my texture but it still looks the same

Comment: Numpad 1 _and_ 5, if necessary, to get an Orthogonal, (non-perspective) view?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, thanks anyway

Comment: can u provide blend file?